# Passing arguments as an object in function but in unit tests it is undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to understand why passing function arguments as an object works in my code, but not in my unit test. For example

```
const arg1 = "foo";
const arg2 = "bar";

function myFunc({arg1, arg2}) {
    console.log(arg1); // "foo"
    console.log(arg2); // "bar"
    return { "name": arg1, "colour": arg2 };
}
```

Above works just as expected. However trying to test comes back as `undefined`.

```
describe("myFunc", () => {
    const mockArg1 = "mockFoo";
    const mockArg2 = "mockBar";

    it("should return an object with name set as arg1", () => {
        expect(
            myFunc({
              mockArg1,
              mockArg2
            }).name
        ).toBe("mockFoo");
    });
});
```

When I run the above test, the values of `mockArg1` and `mockArg2` are `undefined` in the function, even though I've passed them through inside an object exactly as my function expects.

What am I doing wrong in the syntax of this `expect` call of `myFunc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the myFunc like this:

```js
describe("myFunc", () => {
    const mockArg1 = "mockFoo";
    const mockArg2 = "mockBar";

    it("should return an object with name set as arg1", () => {
        expect(
            myFunc({
              arg1: mockArg1, // !!!
              arg2: mockArg2  // !!!
            }).name
        ).toBe("mockFoo");
    });
});
```

as you expect the arguments to be called `arg1` and `arg2`

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that the whole point of calling with an object was so I had named arguments, I feel like a fool for not realising.

Comment: No worries @user1486133 it happens :) I can remember that many times I was trying to solve something with searching for an answer and some small mistake that I've made was the reason. Happy coding :)